# SoapUI CE and ReadyAPI (SoapUI NG) encode URLs differently

Tags: soapui, readyapi

I have created an HTTP request to the URL below in SoapUI (v5) and SoapUI Pro NG (ReadyAPI v2.0):

> [http://localhost:8888/content-service/content/book?query=(collection="book title")](http://localhost:8888/content-service/content/book?query=(collection=%22book%20Ptitle%22))

However, the encoding of the URL sent appears to differ between the two.  It looks like SoapUI is encoding the quotes to `%20` and `%22` respectively.

In SoapUI Pro NG it seems to be encoding the URL twice, converting the `%` to `%25` followed by the `22`, resulting in `%2522`.

Why do the free edition and the paid edition have different encoding behaviours?

*Sent using SoapUI Pro NG:*

```
GET http://localhost:8888/content-service/content/book?query=(collection=%2522book%title%2522) HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_112)
```

*Sent using SoapUI:*

```
GET http://localhost:8888/content-service/content/book?query=(collection=%22book%20title%22) HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

I have tried disabling URL encoding and putting in `%20` or `%22` but this results in the reverse behaviour occurring.

Comment: also raised with SmartBear support
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/SoapUI-CE-and-ReadyAPI-SoapUI-NG-encode-URLs-differently/m-p/146200#M33234

Comment: Investigation so far indicated endpoints and query follow different encoding patterns.   Will update further as I work out more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have discovered the issue.

A REST GET request to a URL using SoapUI follows different encoding rules to an HTTP GET request.

Smartbear were unable to provide a reason for the difference in behaviours